# How to multiply every column in one dataframe with all columns in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `X_dummy` and `X_var`, where `X_dummy` contains dummies and looks like this:

```
dummy1 dummy2 
 1       0     
 0       1      
 1       0
```

The `X_var` dataframe looks contains variables and looks like this:

```
var1 var2 
 4    2    
 10   5    
 1    1
```

Now I want to create a dataframe containing the cellwise product of every column from `X_dummy` with the complete `X_var` dataframe. Hence, my resulting dataframe should look like, `X_result`:

```
var1dummy1  var2dummy1  var1dummy2  var2dummy2  

    4           2           0          0                  
    0           0           10         5                     
    1           1           0          0
```

Does anyone know how to do this without using multiple for loops?

Answer (score 4):

Something like `numpy` broadcast

```
new = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df2.T.values * df1.T.values[:,None]).T)
new
Out[161]: 
   0  1   2  3
0  4  2   0  0
1  0  0  10  5
2  1  1   0  0
##new.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns,df2.columns]).map('_'.join)
```

Comment: I need to think of this first next time.   +1

Comment: @ScottBoston ah I just spend time on it, since it is different than the regular broadcast ~

Comment: "different than 'regular broadcast'"?   Okay, a couple of questions here.  What is regular broadcasting and how does it differ from what you've done here?

Comment: @ScottBoston usually broadcast one cell and do the calculation more like applymap, For this case  the whole column need to be considered as one item and broadcast ( `T `here) , since we need to put one whole column into one sub-array.

Comment: I need an advanced Numpy course. or like a six month long project where I must use numpy to do some calculations/manipulations.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
pd.concat([(df1[i]*df2[j]).rename(f'{i}{j}') for i in df1 for j in df2], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   dummy1var1  dummy1var2  dummy2var1  dummy2var2
0           4           2           0           0
1           0           0          10           5
2           1           1           0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do it with one loop:

```
dummies = X_dummy.astype(bool)
pd.concat([X_var.loc[dummies[c]] for c in dummies], axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
#   var1  var2  var1  var2
#0     4     2     0     0
#1     0     0    10     5
#2     1     1     0     0
```

Note that because one of your dataframes contains dummies, you do not need multiplication at all.